# Porting struts1 project to Maven - Correct ApplicationResources file path

Tags: java, maven, struts, struts-1, resourcebundle

I'm trying to convert a regular Struts 1.2 Eclipse project to Maven.

I managed to add all dependencies required by the project and everything compiles and executes fine, except for message bundles not being loaded correctly (while they are working correctly in the non-maven project).

This is the struts-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        [...]
    </form-beans>
    <global-exceptions>
        [...]
    </global-exceptions>
    <global-forwards>
        [...]
    </global-forwards>
    <action-mappings>
        [...]
    </action-mappings>
    <controller>
        <set-property property="maxFileSize" value="700M" />
        <set-property property="nocache" value="true" />
    </controller>
    <message-resources null="false" parameter="agv.ApplicationResources" />
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
        <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
        <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
    </plug-in>
</struts-config>
```

This is the structure of the project:

```
- myproject
  + src
    + agv
      - ApplicationResources_de.properties
      - ApplicationResources_en.properties
      - ApplicationResources_it.properties
      + other packages under agv
  + WebContent
  + Other directories
```

This is the code that lists the message bundles:

```
//languages = ['it', 'en', 'de']
for (Iterator iter = languages.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    language = (Language) iter.next();

    try {
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("agv.ApplicationResources", language.getLocale());
    }
    catch (MissingResourceException ex) {
        Logger.log(this.getClass()).warn("Missing Resource Bundle for Locale " + language.getLocale() + ", skipping...");
        continue;
    }
}
```

This, on the eclipse version outputs nothing, and resource bundles get correctly loaded, while on the Maven version of the project, it outputs

```
Missing Resource Bundle for Locale it, skipping...
Missing Resource Bundle for Locale en, skipping...
Missing Resource Bundle for Locale de, skipping...
```

And I see labels getting rendered like `??? agv.main.hello ???`.

I'm sure I'm missing something.

The pom.xml is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>agv</groupId>
    <artifactId>agv</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>agv</name>
    <description>agv</description>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/agv</directory> <!-- The directory where ApplicationResources_##.properties are located -->
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>META-INF/context.xml</packagingExcludes>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        [...]
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Does anyone have a clue on what the issue is, and how to deal with it?

Comment: May be you missing some resource bundle for example a default resource bundle?

Comment: @RomanC I don't think so... I mean, the default resource bundle is the english one, and it has always worked until the maven step!

Comment: @BackSlash
I can confirm a simpler and similar problem.  with no additional message resources other than the default a configuration working non-maven copied over does not work but compiles and executes the actions, and fails on the first use of a message resource in the first jsp